# how to set static IP address in opensolaris

Tags: opensolaris, static-ip

in solaris i knew how to do this. Edit /etc/inet/ipnodes, change /etc/defaultrouter, reboot

in opensolaris there is not defaultrouter file.

first thing I tried was System->admin->network
switch to manual
enter static address and netmask and gateway.

press 'activate'

"this interface cannot be activated". No error messages given.

Close widget, open again. Now hangs for a minute and then closes

try edit /etc/inet/ipnodes, reboot

eth card not up. Network widget hangs then closes

Works perfectly on DHCP

Comment: Your steps for earlier Solaris releases are misleading. Setting a static IP address is done by editing /etc/hostname.<interface> and putting either an IP address (preferred) or a hostname in it. Editing /etc/ipnodes (or /etc/hosts) can be used to change the IP address in the latter case only. /etc/defaultrouter isn't part of a default Solaris or OpenSolaris installation so is created by the administrator either directly or by answering questions at config time. OpenSolaris install with dhcp/nwam enabled so you are not prompted for anything regarding network configuration at installation time.

Comment: the fact that the GUI widget totally fails is disappointing, following various google trails shows that this is well known. THose google trails got me working in the end

Comment: nwam is a work in progress. The one you use is phase 0.5, a lot of improvements are in Phase 1 which should be available if future releases (or already downloadable as beta). http://hub.opensolaris.org/bin/view/Project+nwam/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as "Closed Solaris". As far as your Static IP "issue", click the link below.

http://www.google.com/search?q=opensolaris+static+ip

Comment: :-) - the first time I have had my nose rubbed in something so elegantly. Ty - I deserved it

Comment: glad i could help. And i really appreciate that you didn't take my answer as mean spirited, as it was never intended to be that way.

Comment: Solaris 10 and older are Closed (-source) Solaris.